# MySql database selecting count(column) using inner joins

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join, sql

I have three tables

```
USER :         idUser, Username
USERLOCATION : idUser, idLocation
SESSION :      idUser, idSession
```

What I want to find is all the users that are from a particular location and count how many sessions they have had.  I'm nearly there with this SQL

```
    SELECT  u.idUser, u.Username, s.idSession
      FROM  rempad.User u
INNER JOIN  rempad.UserLocation l ON u.idUser = l.idUser
INNER JOIN  rempad.Session s ON u.idUser = s.idUser
     WHERE  l.idLocation = 12
```

This returns all the users belonging to a particular location and all the session ids.  **Where I am stuck is that I really want to be able able to count the the sessions for each user.**

I've tried...

> SELECT u.idUser, u.Username, COUNT(s.idSession) as SessionCount

but this returns only a single row and counts all the sessions in the session table rather than counting the sessions that belong to each individual user at that location.

Do I need to do a nested SELECT statement?  I'm not really sure how to go about writing the query.

Any help much appreciated.

L

Comment: COUNT(blah) as something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT  u.idUser, u.Username, count(s.idSession) as x
      FROM  rempad.User u
INNER JOIN  rempad.UserLocation l ON u.idUser = l.idUser
INNER JOIN  rempad.Session s ON u.idUser = s.idUser
     WHERE  l.idLocation = 12
GROUP  BY u.iduser, 
      u.username
```

Comment: @LindaKeating:- Try using the Group By clause then. Updated my answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be better to use Group by along with the above

```
SELECT u.iduser, 
       u.username, 
       Count(s.idsession) AS x 
FROM   USER u 
       INNER JOIN userlocation l 
               ON u.iduser = l.iduser 
       INNER JOIN session s 
               ON u.iduser = s.iduser 
WHERE  l.idlocation = 12 
GROUP  BY u.iduser, 
          u.username
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a29d/1/0 this is an example, seems to group by user

Comment: Thankyou so much - I had made a mistake when using the group by - but tried it again and it worked.  REally appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that I could help